# Detecting repeating digits in a number

Tags: c++, algorithm, duplicates, unique

I am trying to build a method that would take an integer as input. Then split that integer into single digits and then store them inside a vector. I then use sort() to sort the vector so I can detect any repeating elements within the vector. Upon the first repeat, I want to return True, if no repeat, I want to return False.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
bool RepeatDigit(int number){
vector<int> temp;
while (number > 0){
    int digit = number % 10;
    number /= 10; 
    temp.push_back(digit);
}
sort(temp.begin(),temp.end());
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size() - 1; i++){
    if (temp[i] == temp[i+1]){
        return true;
        break;
    } else { 
        return false;
        break;
    }
}
return(0);
}
```

But when I use this method in my other method to filter out repeating numbers in a if statement:

```
if (numerator % n == 0 && RepeatDigit(numerator) == false){
//Do Stuff
}
```

It does not seem to work properly and numbers with repeating digits still appear to be not filtered out. Can anyone tell me where the problem is? Or is there a more simple to preform this operation?

Comment: If you need more details on how I intend to use this method just ask me and I'll provide more context

Comment: I'd suggest stepping through your code with a debugger and trying to test `RepeatDigit` specifically. In particular, in that `for` loop, while `i` _ever_ reach something other than `0`?

Comment: you don't need a vector because there are only 10 digits. Just a `char digits[10]` is enough

Comment: Having a `break` right after a `return` indicates a misunderstanding of what those lines do. The `break` lines are dead code, code that is never executed.

Comment: When two consecutive digits are not equal, your code should continue checking.  Instead, it returns `false` immediately.

Comment: ah I see what you mean. Was too focused on the == part and did not pay much attention to the else part. Thanks!

Comment: Your last loop can be simplified (and fixed) with `std::adjacent_find`: `return std::adjacent_find(temp.begin(), temp.end()) != temp.end();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your `else` branch - it causes your cycle to break on first iteration, so it only checks if the first digit in `temp` is duplicated.

Moreover, instead of `RepeatDigit(numerator) == false` you could simply write `!RepeatDigit(numerator)`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This new function achieves `O(n)`. It checks if the current digit has already been read:

```cpp
bool IsNumRepeating(int num)
{
    std::array<bool, 10> arr;
    for(; num > 0; num /= 10)
    {
        int digit = num % 10;
        if(arr[digit]) return true;
        arr[digit] = true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Alternatively, you could turn the number into a `std::string` and then check for repeated characters (slower):

```cpp
bool IsNumRepeating(int num)
{
    std::string str = std::to_string(num);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if(std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), str[i]) > 1)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Example:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int num = 1234567891;
    bool check = IsNumRepeating(num);

    std::cout << "Is " << num << " repeating ?: " << (check ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Is 1234567891 repeating ?: true
```

Comment: Your approach with characters is O(n^2), where `n` is the number of digits. The question's approach of sorting then stepping through the vector is O(n lg n). I don't know if I would call your approach an improvement.

Comment: Well, it's not like you can enter more than 2,147,483,647 (10 digits) anyways. I agree that it is slower, but it works and for most cases, it won't be an issue.

Comment: But can you do better? What if I challenged you to use `std::array<bool, 10>` and get the job done in O(n) time?

Comment: @rdbo Even if you don’t completely rewrite the logic, it can still be made marginally better than what you have shown. There is no need to re-check characters you have already checked, or search past a duplicate. So use `str.find()` instead of `std::count()`, using `i+1` as the starting index. Or change the starting iterator that you pass to `std::count()` (better, `std::any_of()`) to `str.begin()+i+1` instead of `str.begin()`, and then you can change the loop to use iterators instead of indexes.

Comment: @JaMiT alright, you win. If you challenged me to use `std::array<bool, 10>` and achieve O(n), I'd ask you to look at my edit on the answer

Comment: @rdbo Good! I think (not sure) that a `std::array` of a primitive type could contain garbage, though, unless initialized with braces, as in `std::array<bool, 10> arr = {};`. On the other hand, sometimes I'm just paranoid about setting initial values.